# Seeding F# random generator to same state as Matlab

Tags: random, f#, math.net

In trying to port over some Matlab code to F#, I'm trying to make sure the translations are accurate. As of now, there are cases where I'm not completely sure whether there are mistakes. Since a lot of the code is statistical in nature, it would be convenient to be able to seed the F# generators to the same state as Matlab's. It would also help with triangulating the exact equations that are wrong. Wanted to ask before I started dumping Matlab generated random numbers to csv files and solving this issue in a manual way.

Comment: It is not just an issue of seeding - are the algorithms even the same?

Comment: I would think one would be able to choose between the major ones, no? A mersenne twister is behind the default random stream in matlab. I would be surprised if one couldn't choose the same in F#.

Comment: I don't think this is guranteed - I believe even for the Mersenne twister there are parameters you can tweak.  Best bet is to just read  random numbers from a file.

Comment: there are different versions of MT. Your best bet is either implement your own MT in both Matlab and F#, or as you suggest download/upload the random sequence.

Comment: You could see if you could use the matlab type provider to use the matlab RNG in F#.  https://github.com/BayardRock/Matlab-Type-Provider

Comment: @mydogisbox I wasn't able to build the matlab type provider unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a definitive answer as probably implementing your own random number generator in matlab and F# should yield the most reliable results. You are also bound to bump into issues of thread safety in .NET, and the shapes of matrices in matlab. For example

In matlab:

```
 rng(200,'twister')
 rand(1,5)
```

> ans =
>
> ```
> 0.9476    0.2265    0.5944    0.4283    0.7641
> ```

In F#:

```
open MathNet.Numerics.Random

let random1b = MersenneTwister(200)
random1b.NextDoubles(5)
```

> val it : float [] =   [|0.9476322592; 0.4941436297; 0.2265474238;
>   0.1485590497; 0.5944201448|]

The 1st, 3rd, and 5th random numbers do match.

Now it's possible you can replicate this somehow by playing around with different versions and/or F# and matlab array dimensions.

The [MathNet Random Docs](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Random.html).

Comment: I don't know anything about F#, but it looks like you may be storing the output of `random1b.NextDoubles` as a `float`. Could that be why only every other value appears to match?

Comment: @horchler I see why this would look confusing. Actually it's the F# compiler inferring the type to be `float array`. Which is correct as [float is a type alias for double in this case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/primitive-types-%5Bfsharp%5D), representing 64-bit floating point numbers. I can just guess that the difference is in how a sequence of random numbers is generated in matlab and .NET.